# Does Fey Ancestry or other resistance grant advantage against Madness saving throws?

Tags: dnd-5e

After our campaign last night, one of my players mentioned they forgot to roll advantage on the saving throws against Madness because they had Fey Ancestry. I don't see anything in the DMG or otherwise that states Madness causes a charmed effect.

So this brought up my question, is there anything that could grant advantage against Madness?

Comment: [Related] [Fey Ancestry - What spells and effects are covered by 'advantage against being charmed'](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/55452) • [Does Fey Ancestry grant advantage on the save against Otto's Irresistible Dance?](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/61723)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Only a game feature (such as a class feature or race feature) that specifically grants advantage against madness, or grants advantage on saving throws against magical effects, assuming the source of the madness is magical (which isn't always the case). For example:

- The Robe of the Archmagi and the Spellguard shield grant advantage on saving throws against spells and magical effect.
- A gnome's Gnome Cunning racial feature allows advantage on Int, Wis, and Cha saving throws against magic
- A monk's diamond soul class feature allows the monk to spend 1 ki point to re-roll a failed saving throw, which isn't advantage, but has an effect very similar to advantage.
- The Wizard's school of abjuration Spell Resistance feature might help if the source of the madness is specifically a spell (which is unlikely)
- Finally, there's inspiration which grants advantage on any d20 roll.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

Fey Ancestry does not confer resistance to Madness

Fey Ancestry.

> You have advantage on saving throws against being charmed, and magic can’t put you to sleep.

Unless the madness was inflicted as a charm effect, there's no reason to give  advantage on the basis of fey ancestry.

Any other resistance to Madness would be related to how Madness was inflicted upon the creature / character.  Anything that grants advantage on the save isn't against Madness, per se, but the means by which Madness is being inflicted. (Typically, a spell or a curse).

Going Mad(SRD p. 206)

> Certain spells, such as  contact other plane and symbol, can cause
>   insanity. (snip) Diseases, poisons, and planar effects such as psychic
>   wind or the howling winds of Pandemonium can all inflict madness. 
>   Some artifacts can also break the psyche of a character who uses or
>   becomes attuned to them.  Resisting a madness‑inducing effect usually
>   requires a Wisdom or Charisma saving throw.